# htaccess deny acces to directory if logged out (checked with php)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to deny access to visitors to a specific directory if they are not logged in.
And redirect them to a "you are not logged in" .html file.

How can I do this? Is there some way to edit .htaccess with php if logged out?

Comment: apache has no knowledge of your "login" status, unless you're using http-level authentication (e.g. 'basic'). you could check for the existence of a session cookie, but that's pretty much useless, because apache can't read PHP sessions to see if that session is a "logged in" one.

Comment: I won't do that with `.htaccess` - I doubt it would be possible unless using Apache AUTH, so I'd go by checking that user is logged in on that concrete page and if not redirect him (with PHP) to a 403 error page...

Comment: this post might helpful

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166792/password-protected-directory-and-files-in-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166792/password-protected-directory-and-files-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with Apache.

One way to achieve this would be to forward every requests to a php script via a rewrite rule and to serve files via this PHP script.

But this is heavy, if your files are big, this is not a good solution.

Maybe you should look as the [Apache dbd auth mod](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) (if you have your users in a database). But again, this should not be the job of Apache because it's not good at it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Apache job, but PHP can do it for you.

On a public-only page, define no session parameters.

On a public login page, define all session parameters.

On a member-only page, start a session as is :

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    // Assuming variables have been initally defined
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) AND isset($_SESSION['password']))
    {
        echo 'You are now logged in';
            header('Location: sosecretpage.php');
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'You are not logged in. You dont have access to this page';
    }
    ?>
```