# How do I disallow download file through direct url access?

Tags: c#, php, apache

I am currently working on a project that allows user to update and patch their application when updates are available. I am using Apache as web server and put my patch files in the webroot. The application download the patch files through https (I am using a patching system bought from unity assets stores. It supports http, https and ftp. It is done in c#). I have disable directory listing for better security, however I still able to download specific files through browser if I specify the path. For example:
https://example.com/patch/test.txt

Is there any way I can restrict user from downloading the files directly through url? Is there any better approach that I can improve the security?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block direct download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550660/how-to-block-direct-download-file)

Comment: Keep your patch files outside of web root itself. Change your URL from `https://example.com/patch/test.txt` to `https://example.com/patch?filename=test.txt`. Now, get the `filename` value in your PHP file and have the download accordingly by reading the file from the folder which outside of webroot(public_html).   You can also have authentication to allow download only to specific users.

Comment: Hi prakhar, thank you for your reply. Does the solution allow download bunch of files and also directories? I am not familiar with http headers but the patching files include bunch of files and directories.

Comment: If you want to download the files without allowing direct access, You should use Authentication at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow only specific ips:

```
<Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.
</Location>
```

If the application is installed on the same pc as the browser,  then you are out of luck. You might be able to do some magic with user agents,  but that is hackable by pretty much anyone with postman.

This is why we prefer to store these in databases, file servers or blob storage, so that we can also secure them.

Comment: Hi, thank your for reply. I have though about using file servers but unfortunately the patching system seems like doesn't support ftps protocol, only ftp protocol. I am asking the creator of the patch system about the ftps support.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent file download when:

- User copy & paste URL directly into browser and hit enter
- User clicking direct link
  from some other website

You may consider the following options:

- Your **Update Client** set *Custom HTTP Header* or *Cookies* prior to
  requesting file from server, then **Server (PHP)** check if *either of them* is
  presence then serve the file.
- Since you are using Apache web server, you could use [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to do the same as above option.

**Example `.htaccess`:**

Check for Cookie:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !YourMagicCookie=123456 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Check for custom HTTP header:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-YourUpdateClient} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```